# Export 1bit Image

Tags: export, image, binary

I have a binary image like the following one:

[image: binary]

How can I export it as an 1bit image instead of an 8bit one?

If I export it in tiff it automatically becomes an 8bit one.

Best,
Max

Comment: Have you seen the `"BitDepth"` option?

Comment: That Works! Thanks!